# library not found after cocoapods integration

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods, xcode7.2

Integrated (objective C) Xcode 7.2 iOS 9.2:

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/Software/ruby
$ export GEM_HOME=$HOME/Software/ruby
$ gem install cocoa pods  (automatic pods version (0.39))
$ export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Software/ruby/bin
$ cd/ to project folder
$ pod init
$ open -a Xcode Podfile

# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'ProjectName' do

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0.3'
end

target 'ProjectNameTests' do
end

$ pod install
```

Xcode gives error "library not found for -lAFNetworking"

Searched around google: Tried with things:

1. Removed everything from target>build setting>otherlinkerflag, except $(inherited), compiled but unlucky
2. Deintegrated pods plugin from (https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate) again installed compiled but unlucky
3. Tried experiment with header search path & framework search path but unlucky.

Comment: Could you please post the log message of 'pod update --verbose'?

Answer (score 0):

Did you open Workspace or Project file? Verify that you open first one

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure Pods is completely instally !!! 
and open Workspace file geneterated after pods is installed !!